# How to get all clickable views available on an Android Activity

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator, monkeyrunner

I want to write an App Crawler. For that, I want to pick all the clickable Buttons/Images/Icons available on an Android activity. And then click them one by one. What should I use here and How- Appium, UIAutomator, MonkeyRunner or else?

Answer (score 3):

[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) can help you.

This script, which is almost completely generated by `culebra` does what you are trying to do.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013-2017  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2017-04-28 by Culebra v13.3.0
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os


from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

TAG = 'CULEBRA'

_s = 5
_v = '--verbose' in sys.argv


kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1)
kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, **kwargs2)
vc.dump()

def cic(view):
    if view.isClickable():
        print "should click on", view.getId()
        # view.click()

vc.traverse(transform=cic)
```

Notice that if you click on some View and the screen changes you may need to invoke `vc.dump()` again to get the new tree.

Also, take a look at **culebra concertina mode** which does something similar to what you want, explained in some detail [in this post](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2015/08/culebra-concertina-mode.html).

Comment: Hi, I am done with few things to achieve the app crawling: 1. I have installed Culebra-Tester apps as you added me in Beta Testing. 2. I have access the URL provided by the App 3. I have run the curl script. Now I am running the file you provided above (after making few click event changes) through python. As soon as I execute the file, curl script stops with "shortMessage=crash" error. And then nothing happens. Please guide me. What's wrong I am doing here.

Comment: CulebraTester, the code generator, and culebra scritps are mutually exclusive. The script deliberately kills any instance of CulebraTester found still running when starts. Once you are done generating the script you should exit CulebraTester via Quit (in shortcuts).

Comment: @DhirajAggarwal thanks for your comment. It helped me to update the documentation at https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester-public/wiki/Getting-started